# Restkit json error response msg from server

Tags: ios, json, api, response, restkit

I have used many hours on how to solve this issue. Im using Restkit 0.9.3 with Object Mapping 2.0. All data is in JSON. I can make GET, POST, PUT and DELETE operations correctly, it's the response body I dont catch and map corretly..

So my problem is that my restful api is returning errors when something goes wrong. I want to map those errors with restkit, fx this error is returned:

**{
  "code": "401",
  "message": "Unauthorized"
}**

**How do I map this json correct?** I have tried lots of things and could use some guideness - or please give an example of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For version 0.10.0 this response error can be mapped as follows:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping mapKeyPath:@"message" toAttribute:@"errorMessage"];
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] setErrorMapping:errorMapping];
```

Requests that return an error will call the following delegate method:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSArray *errorMessages = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey];
    RKErrorMessage *errorMessage = [errorMessages objectAtIndex:0]; // First and only object in your case.
    NSString *message = [errorMessage errorMessage];
    NSInteger code = [[objectLoader response] statusCode];
    NSLog(@"ERROR: [%d] %@", code, message); // => ERROR: [401] Unauthorized
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this in v.20?

Comment: see my answer below for v0.20

Comment: What if the JSON response is in this format: { "message": "Unauthorized", "critical":true } ? Where can I get the value for the key 'critical'?

Answer (score 29):

**For RestKit v0.20**

assuming your HTTP body is:

```
{"error": "..."}
```

you create an the mapping and descriptor:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];

[errorMapping addPropertyMapping: [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *errorResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:errorResponseDescriptor];
```

and then you can access it from your failure block:

```
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"errorMessage: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey]);
            }
```

This uses the built-in `RKErrorMessage` class, though you can create your own custom class with additional fields.

Comment: This doesn't work.  The error comesback null. NSLOG shows errorMessage: (null)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736408/restkit-failure-getting-access-to-the-json-returned

Comment: Works fine for me and others. Are you using the correct mapping for your class?

Comment: @jgervin would you care to share your JSON? I'd like that -1 turned to a +1 :]

Answer (score 5):

Using **Restkit v0.2x** you can map all JSON attributes you want to the already existing `RKErrorMessage.userInfo` Dictionary property in this [**Swift**] way:

```
let errorMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: RKErrorMessage.self);
errorMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "userInfo"));

let errorResponseDescriptor = RKResponseDescriptor(
    mapping: errorMapping,
    method: RKRequestMethod.Any,
    pathPattern: nil,
    keyPath: "error", //or nil, according to your json response
    statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)))
);
```

So, you can map an error JSON response like this one:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Error message",
        "cause": "...",
        "code": "my_error_code",
        "url": "..."
        ...
    }
}
```

And retrieve the `RKErrorMessage` with all attributes, in a `failure` closure, as follows:

```
failure: { (operation, error) -> Void in
    if let errorMessage = error.userInfo?[RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey]?.firstObject as? RKErrorMessage{
        let message = errorMessage.userInfo["message"] as! String;
        let code = errorMessage.userInfo["code"] as! String;
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope this can be helpful to someone!

Comment: Instead of `statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(UInt(RKStatusCodeClassClientError))`you could also use `statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.ClientError)`

Answer (score 0):

if an object is returned your delegate should call this method:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {}
```

in this method you should call an instance of your "error" class and map 'code' and 'message' as necessary.

An easier way to handle errors though would be to use:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {

if(objectLoader.response.statusCode == 401)
{ ...
```

And show the necessary error message in that method.