# Getting Error Descriptions From Restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

When my web service returns an error, I want to display the error message that was sent back with the response. I can't find any way of doing this in RestKit. I've tried setting the error mapping property of the object manager, and using the following suggestion:

[Restkit json error response msg from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841203/restkit-json-error-response-msg-from-server)

But this doesn't work for me. For one thing, RKErrorMessage doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for RestKit ~> 0.22.0

```
// Setup error mapping
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping: [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"errorDescription" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *errorResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                             method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:nil
                                                                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:errorResponseDescriptor];
```

Answer (score 0):

In v.20 you have to do two things:

First, import the RKErrorMessage.h file:

> `#import <RestKit/RKErrorMessage.h>`

Then, add the error mapping to your objectManager:

> ```
> RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
>     [errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
>     [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"error" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)]];
> ```