# Restkit failure: getting access to the json returned

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using Restkit .20 and trying to get the error object returned in a failure block. I have tried both below and both return (null) for the error object.

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:
 [RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                                                    keyPath:@"error" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[errorDescriptor]];
```

AND

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"error" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"error" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)]];
```

This is in my failure block which prints out "errorMessage: (null)"

```
 failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
{
        NSLog(@"errorMessage: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey]);
}
```

Here is what is return from in the JSON from the server.

```
{
    "status": "FAIL",
    "user_errors": null,
    "error": "Credit card type is not accepted by this merchant account.",
    "user": null
}
```

Comment: Your first set of code looks right. What does a mapping trace log say and what do you get when just logging the error itself (not just part of the user info)?

Comment: ...ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0xadd5ce0 {DetailedErrors=(
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: user
The representation inputted to the mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the following key paths: code, error
This likely indicates that you have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched., keyPath=null}

Comment: Is this dependent on the header error code?  The header is giving back a 201. But the data is the JSON I mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP status code 201 is a success code, not an error code so your error mapping will not be tried (because of `statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)`).

So, update the server to send an appropriate status code. If you update the response descriptor to check 'successful' responses for errors I think it will work.

Comment: What response should I return with a 401? I need to return with a response that says, you didnt respond with the correct information.

Comment: You can return whatever combination of error code and body data you want, just define it and code to it.